# Как защититься от вирусов-вымогателей Petya и Misha?

Tags: вирусы, wannacry, petya, misha

Прочитал, что предотвратить шифрование данных вирусом можно с помощью создания файла `perfc`:

> Специалисты *Positive Technologies* нашли локальный *“kill switch”* для
>   *Petya*, остановить шифровальщика можно создав файл *C:\Windows\perfc*
>   (*perfc* — файл без расширения).

а также установкой патчей с сайта *Microsoft*.

Существуют ли еще какие-либо превентивные меры, кроме само собой разумеющихся (не открывать непонятные ссылки/письма и т.д.)?

Comment: "Первая версия" wannacry падала при наличии пингуемого доменного имени - если есть сэмпл, загляните внутрь)

Comment: Читайте https://habrahabr.ru/company/infosecurity/blog/331788/ и все будет хорошо :Р

Comment: Самое эфективное средство защиты от вирусов, это поставить линукс, или отключиться полностью от интернета

Comment: @pavel1787mego , почитайте https://habrahabr.ru/company/cloud4y/blog/330660/. Так что и линукс этому подвержен

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Создаем файл perfc**

В момент атаки *Petya* ищет файл *C:\Windows\perfc*. Если такой файл на компьютере уже есть, то вирус заканчивает работу без заражения.

Чтобы создать такой файл для защиты от *Petya* можно использовать обычный "Блокнот". Специалисты также советуют сделать файл доступным только для чтения, чтобы вирус не мог внести в него изменения.

**WMIC и PSEXEC**

Вирус распространяется через службы *WMIC* и *PSEXEC*. Чтобы отключить службу *WMIC* выполняем в командной строке (*cmd.exe*) следующую команду:

```
net stop winmgmt
```

Более подробно: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/enus/library/aa826517(v=vs.85).aspx

**Поставить патчи безопасности**

Вирус также распространяется через уязвимости Windows CVE-2017-0199  и CVE-2017-0144. Рекомендуется поставить патчи безопасности, которые их закрывают:

https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-US/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2017-0199
https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-US/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2017-0144

Надо поставить патчи безопасности не только для *Windows*, но и для *Microsoft Office*.

Также необходимо поставить патчи, закрывающие ранее эксплуатируемую уязвимость для WannaCry:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms17-010.aspx

**Обновить сигнатуры антивирусов**

База сигнатур антивирусного ПО должна быть обновлена от 27.06.2017 не ранее 20:00.

**Отключить TCP-порты**

Если в сети уже имеются зараженные рабочие станции или серверы необходимо отключить TCP-порты 1024-1035, 135 и 445.

**Отключить протокол SMB**

В случае невозможности установки обновлений безопасности отключить протокол *SMB v1/v2/v3* на рабочих станциях и серверах.

Подробнее: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and-windows

**Настроить блокировку атак**

В случае наличия средств защиты типа *NGFW / NGTP / IPS* настроить блокировку атак, эксплуатирующих EternalBlue (MS17-010).

**Если заражение все же произошло**

**Отключение системы**

Если заражение все же произошло, то по некоторым публикациям в сети помогает экстренное отключение машины сразу как только появится сообщение от вируса. В этом случае он не успеет зашифровать файлы на компьютере.

Подробнее: https://twitter.com/hackerfantastic/status/879775570766245888

**Не переводить деньги**

Ни в коем случае не переводите деньги на счет злоумышленников, их электронная почта заблокирована, и вы в любом случае не сможете таким образом восстановить данные.

Comment: Исчерпывающий ответ. Спасибо!

Comment: Небольшое предупреждение. Если сделать это все сразу - велика вероятность что сломается что-то позарез нужное.

Comment: @PavelMayorov для начала неплохо установить указанные патчи безопасности и обновить сигнатуры антивирусов. остальное уже опционально. можно сделать трюк с созданием файла, но тут нет никаких гарантий, что в новых версиях вируса разработчики не уберут этот kill switch.

Comment: А в трое с каких хэшом он ищет именно perfc.dll? Это тонкий намек на то, что многое написанное в ответе не соответствует действительности.

Comment: создание файла perfc.dll это не панацея. судя по антивирусным отчетам первая версия вируса имела этот kill switch, потом его разработчики все же убрали.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов по поводу вашего замечания "не соответствует действительности" - внимательно выслушаю ваши комментарии относительно остальной части ответа. что именно по вашему мнению не соответствует действительности?

Comment: Имя файла perfc.dll не соответствует действительности. Хэш троя с такой проверкой в студию!

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов "Имя файла perfc.dll не соответствует действительности" по поводу этого замечания я уже писал комментарий выше, в различных сборках присутствует kill switch с именем файла perfc.dll, perfc.dat или perfc.

Comment: Дайте хэш хоть одной сборки с .dll или с .dat.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов это рекомендации ESET (http://support.eset.com/alert6488/?viewlocale=en_US). попробуйте обратиться к ним, чтобы получить нужную сборку.

Comment: Я попробую донести мысль еще раз: НЕТ такого варианта Petya или Wanacry, который проверяет .dll или .dat. Указанные для блокировки адреса тоже не имеют ни к Пете, ни к Wanacry никакого(!) отношения. Пока нет доказательств обратного, то есть  хэша файла с указанным поведением. У Eset написано не только про dll файл, а также про тот, что реально проверяется. Чувствуете разницу?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов у них написано 3 варианта. ок, поправлю ответ в соответствии с вашими рекомендация, но в различных источниках присутствуют данные про расширения dll и dat. врут?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов это публикуют достаточно авторитетные антивирусные компании.

Comment: Не врут, а ошибаются. Нет ни одного примера такого файла, ссылки к Пете тоже отношения не имеют.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов все может быть. ок, оставил в ответе файл без расширения. что касается ссылок, надо будет уточнить информацию. пока оставил.

Comment: Информация о ссылках - от ЦБ РФ. Проверяли - не было там Пети.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов ок, удалил этот раздел.

Answer (score 8):

Добавлю рекомендации для тех, у кого AD

**Смените пароль администраторам домена** и не вводите его больше на компьютерах пользователей

Один из путей распространения вируса - через сохраненный в системе хеш пароля администратора домена.

**Выключите уже наконец протокол NTLM**

До тех пор, пока злоумышленник может выбирать между NTLM и Kerberos - вся продвинутая безопасность последнего не имеет смысла.